# Docker support needed, SpringBoot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker

**I dockerized my springboot application as below**

```
> FROM openjdk:19-jdk-alpine
> COPY target/microservice-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar microservice-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
> EXPOSE 8080
> CMD ["java","-jar","/microservice-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

When launched from eclipse IDE it will give no problem, with once i run docker image sxpose the port and map it it gives me white label error.
**My pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.login</groupId>
    <artifactId>microservice</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>skam-loginm</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>19</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**Not using RestController as jsp pages are returned**

```
package com.login.java;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.login.java.model.user;
import com.login.java.model.userInterface;

@Controller
public class LoginController 
{
    @Autowired
    private userInterface userInterface;
    @Autowired
    private RegistrationService registrationService;

    
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String checkMVC()
    {
        return "login";
    }

    @GetMapping("/home")
    public String homePage()
    {
        return "home";
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/login")
    public String loginHomepage(@RequestParam("username") String username, @RequestParam("password") String password, Model model)
    {
        user u,u1;
        try 
        {
            System.out.println(username + "-" + password);
            u = userInterface.findByUsername(username);
            //u = userInterface.findById(1);
            System.out.print(u.getPassword().toString() + u.getUsername().toString());
            //u1 = (user) userInterface.findAll();
            //System.out.println(u1.getEmail());
        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Not FOund");
            return "login";
        }
        
        
        if(u!=null && u.getPassword().toString().equals(password))
        {
            model.addAttribute("username",username);
            //System.out.println(u1);
            return "home";
        }
        return "login";
    }
    @PostMapping("/register")
    public String register(@RequestParam("email") String email,
                           @RequestParam("password") String password,
                           @RequestParam("confirm-password") String confirmPassword,
                           Model model) {
        if (!password.equals(confirmPassword)) {
            model.addAttribute("error", "Passwords do not match");
            return "register";
        }
        String response = registrationService.registerUser(email, password, email);
        model.addAttribute("message", response);
        return "login";
    }
    @GetMapping("/register")
    public String registerHomepage()
    {
        return "register";
    }
}
```

[Dockerized Container Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PV6RW.png)

**Docker Logs**

```
> 2023-11-04 20:14:18   .   ____          _            __ _ _
> 2023-11-04 20:14:18  /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
> 2023-11-04 20:14:18 ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
> 2023-11-04 20:14:18  \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
> 2023-11-04 20:14:18   '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
> 2023-11-04 20:14:18  =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
> 2023-11-04 20:14:18  :: Spring Boot ::                (v3.1.2)
> 2023-11-04 20:14:18 
> 2023-11-04 20:14:18 2023-11-04T14:44:18.965Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.login.java.SkamLoginmApplication     : Starting SkamLoginmApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT using Java 19-ea with PID 1 (/microservice-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar started by root in /)
> 2023-11-04 20:14:18 2023-11-04T14:44:18.967Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.login.java.SkamLoginmApplication     : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
> 2023-11-04 20:14:19 2023-11-04T14:44:19.960Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode
> 2023-11-04 20:14:19 2023-11-04T14:44:19.963Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JDBC repositories in DEFAULT mode.
> 2023-11-04 20:14:20 2023-11-04T14:44:20.004Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] .RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport : Spring Data JDBC - Could not safely identify store assignment for repository candidate interface com.login.java.model.userInterface; If you want this repository to be a JDBC repository, consider annotating your entities with one of these annotations: org.springframework.data.relational.core.mapping.Table.
> 2023-11-04 20:14:20 2023-11-04T14:44:20.006Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 36 ms. Found 0 JDBC repository interfaces.
> 2023-11-04 20:14:20 2023-11-04T14:44:20.022Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Multiple Spring Data modules found, entering strict repository configuration mode
> 2023-11-04 20:14:20 2023-11-04T14:44:20.024Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
> 2023-11-04 20:14:20 2023-11-04T14:44:20.058Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 30 ms. Found 1 JPA repository interfaces.
> 2023-11-04 20:14:20 2023-11-04T14:44:20.676Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
> 2023-11-04 20:14:20 2023-11-04T14:44:20.690Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
> 2023-11-04 20:14:20 2023-11-04T14:44:20.690Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine    : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.11]
> 2023-11-04 20:14:21 2023-11-04T14:44:21.005Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner     : At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
> 2023-11-04 20:14:21 2023-11-04T14:44:21.146Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
> 2023-11-04 20:14:21 2023-11-04T14:44:21.148Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2075 ms
> 2023-11-04 20:14:21 2023-11-04T14:44:21.349Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
> 2023-11-04 20:14:21 2023-11-04T14:44:21.434Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 6.2.6.Final
> 2023-11-04 20:14:21 2023-11-04T14:44:21.437Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000406: Using bytecode reflection optimizer
> 2023-11-04 20:14:21 2023-11-04T14:44:21.593Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.h.b.i.BytecodeProviderInitiator        : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : bytebuddy
> 2023-11-04 20:14:21 2023-11-04T14:44:21.762Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.o.j.p.SpringPersistenceUnitInfo      : No LoadTimeWeaver setup: ignoring JPA class transformer
> 2023-11-04 20:14:21 2023-11-04T14:44:21.779Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
> 2023-11-04 20:14:22 2023-11-04T14:44:22.360Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-1 - Added connection com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl@7da10b5b
> 2023-11-04 20:14:22 2023-11-04T14:44:22.363Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
> 2023-11-04 20:14:22 2023-11-04T14:44:22.620Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.h.b.i.BytecodeProviderInitiator        : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : bytebuddy
> 2023-11-04 20:14:23 2023-11-04T14:44:23.223Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
> 2023-11-04 20:14:23 2023-11-04T14:44:23.282Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
> 2023-11-04 20:14:23 2023-11-04T14:44:23.931Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
> 2023-11-04 20:14:23 2023-11-04T14:44:23.952Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.login.java.SkamLoginmApplication     : Started SkamLoginmApplication in 5.51 seconds (process running for 6.342)
> 2023-11-04 20:15:09 2023-11-04T14:45:09.171Z  INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
> 2023-11-04 20:15:09 2023-11-04T14:45:09.172Z  INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
> 2023-11-04 20:15:09 2023-11-04T14:45:09.173Z  INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 1 ms
> 2023-11-04 20:16:30 2023-11-04T14:46:30.863Z  WARN 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : No mapping for GET /favicon.ico
```

**The Logs with debug enabled.**

```
    2023-11-04 22:00:25 2023-11-04T16:30:25.860Z  INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-11-04 22:00:25 2023-11-04T16:30:25.861Z  INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-11-04 22:00:25 2023-11-04T16:30:25.861Z DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected StandardServletMultipartResolver
2023-11-04 22:00:25 2023-11-04T16:30:25.861Z DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver
2023-11-04 22:00:25 2023-11-04T16:30:25.861Z DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected FixedThemeResolver
2023-11-04 22:00:25 2023-11-04T16:30:25.863Z DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected org.springframework.web.servlet.view.DefaultRequestToViewNameTranslator@45cec376
2023-11-04 22:00:25 2023-11-04T16:30:25.863Z DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Detected org.springframework.web.servlet.support.SessionFlashMapManager@41294371
2023-11-04 22:00:25 2023-11-04T16:30:25.864Z DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : enableLoggingRequestDetails='false': request parameters and headers will be masked to prevent unsafe logging of potentially sensitive data
2023-11-04 22:00:25 2023-11-04T16:30:25.864Z  INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 3 ms
2023-11-04 22:00:25 2023-11-04T16:30:25.872Z DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : GET "/", parameters={}
2023-11-04 22:00:25 2023-11-04T16:30:25.883Z DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to com.login.java.LoginController#checkMVC()
2023-11-04 22:00:25 2023-11-04T16:30:25.896Z DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Selected 'text/html' given [text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/avif, image/webp, application/xml;q=0.9, */*;q=0.8]
2023-11-04 22:00:25 2023-11-04T16:30:25.896Z DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.servlet.view.InternalResourceView  : View name 'login', model {}
2023-11-04 22:00:25 2023-11-04T16:30:25.898Z DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.servlet.view.InternalResourceView  : Forwarding to [/WEB-INF/login.jsp]
2023-11-04 22:00:25 2023-11-04T16:30:25.901Z DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 404 NOT_FOUND
2023-11-04 22:00:25 2023-11-04T16:30:25.902Z DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : "ERROR" dispatch for GET "/error", parameters={}
2023-11-04 22:00:25 2023-11-04T16:30:25.904Z DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
2023-11-04 22:00:25 2023-11-04T16:30:25.914Z DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Selected 'text/html' given [text/html, text/html;q=0.8]
2023-11-04 22:00:25 2023-11-04T16:30:25.918Z DEBUG 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Exiting from "ERROR" dispatch, status 404
2023-11-04 22:01:11 2023-11-04T16:31:11.917Z DEBUG 1 --- [ionShutdownHook] o.s.b.a.ApplicationAvailabilityBean      : Application availability state ReadinessState changed from ACCEPTING_TRAFFIC to REFUSING_TRAFFIC
```

Help please Thank you

Full log file i think is not required but is below
https://pastebin.com/fqra3ttz

Couldn't find anything on internet.

Comment: What happens in the log when you get the white label error? Also, it might help setting log levels to debug.

Comment: 2023-11-04 21:08:09 2023-11-04T15:38:09.235Z  INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-11-04 21:08:09 2023-11-04T15:38:09.236Z  INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-11-04 21:08:09 2023-11-04T15:38:09.240Z  INFO 1 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 4 ms
Is what i get at most
And how to set it to debug mode?

Comment: I think it's better if you update you post rather than trying to fit the log messages in the comment field. You change the log level by adding logging.level.org.springframework=DEBUG to your application.properties. Adjust package name part (org.springframework) as needed.

Comment: Alr seems like once build the WEB-INF becomes empty. Updated the logs

Comment: If you change the logging to logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG it won't log that much, but you will still find the issue. The reason for the white label error is that it can't show the error page you'd've wanted, a 404 page that is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Fixed**

Just converted it into .war file and SpringBoot App was alble to package my jsp pages.

Comment: Sorry for late response this worked